# Слог без гласной?

Tags: поэзия, орфоэпия

Некто Saveliy осчастливил интернет-общественность стихом [`Сказ о "Непроданном времени"`](http://stihoslov.ru/stihi/skaz-o-neprodannom-vremeni-saveliy-0), ну а я по крайне уважительной причине (зуд в передних конечностях) стал его анализировать на предмет ритмичности. Есть там такие строки:

```
Хм... А что? Интересно... а вдруг - не туфта,  --/--/--/--/  
И товар - это то, что мне надо?                --/--/--/-         
Позвонил и услышал прелестное: «Да!            --/--/--/--/        
Вас приветствует «Служба из Ада»...»           --/--/--/-
```

Вполне хороший 3-4-стопный анапест. Но что же получается – «Хм…» в начале строки, скопище согласных без единой гласной, таки образует полноценный (и, может быть, даже ударный) слог? Пытался представить, что гласная где-то звучит, но не пишется – что-то не представляется… При анализе написал жалкое «Хмы». Но это ж – не дело… Причём зловредное «Хм…» вполне заменимо на  «Ммм…»

Не подскажете – есть где-то разбор подобных орфоэпических ситуаций?

Answer (score 5):

Именно так. 
Только не Хмы, а хЫм. С кратким Ы. Аналогично Ммм - только тут скорее Эмммм или Умммм - кто как слышит. Сонорные вполне могут образовывать слог. Хотя начало строки - вообще случай не очень убедительный, там и внестопный слог может проскакивать - и отсутствующий (прочтите вообще без Хм - метра не испортит), но здесь все предельно ясно.

Специально разбирать это вряд ли кто будет, надо просто принять к сведению.

Кстати, помнится о подобном мы уже говорили. Я вот этот пример приводил:

Ревет сынок. Побит за двойку с плюсом,
Жена на локоны взяла последний рубль,
Супруг, убитый лавочкой и флюсом,
Подсчитывает месячную убыль.

(Саша Черный)
***Рубль*** рифмуется с ***убыль***.

//-----------------------

> не хочется ... вставлять

А кто Вас, пардон спрашивает? В своей речи Вы вправе говорить так или иначе - в рамках общих орфоэпических норм, а тут надо следовать поэту (ну постольку постольку нет сомнений в его вменяемости) и доверять тому, что он слышит так или иначе.

Вопрос, как я понимаю, в том, есть ли там гласная - и произносится ли она.

Мне сейчас катастрофически некогда, просто нашел одну цитатку - хоть и косвенно, но все-таки хоть какая-то теория ко всем этим примерам.

> Правда, некоторые из этих рассуждений покажутся нам чуждыми. Нам непонятны упорные стычки с александрийским стихом, разбор значения в стихе "е muet"" и т. д. Но если мы займемся легкой аналогией, то увидим, что роль александрийского размера у нас играл и играет четырехстопный ямб, наш казенный размер, -- и нам делается понятна ненависть против этого временщика. "Е muet" y нас как будто бы не существует (произносимость твердого и мягкого знака, долгота "ять" и "е" у нас еще не разобраны), но разве нет у нас слогов с непроизносимой гласной {"Сфера, чей центр повсюду, окружность нигде" (К Бальмонт).}, напр., в словах сентябрь, центр, люстр, алебастр и др., и разве мало пролили чернил за их произносимость?

Вадим Шершеневич.  "От переводчика" к "Теории свободного стиха".

[Теория свободного стиха | az.lib.ru](http://az.lib.ru/s/shershenewich_w_g/text_1920_teoria_svobodnogo_stiha.shtml)

Вот он тоже говорит о ***непроизносимой гласной*** в этом злосчастном примере.

Остальное - позже. Видимо придётся изложить свою позицию подробнее.

//-----------------------
@Людмила

> А насчёт слова"театр":в русском языке 2 слога, Вы правы.В ритмологии по Квятковскому именно в этой строфе -1,он читается кратко"т(иа)тр", не растягивается, иначе неверно будут переданы интонации автора,

Людмила, в чем я "прав"? 
У Квятковского черным по белому:

> Характерно, что поэтический слух обнаруживает двусложие в таких односложных словах, как «центр» и «театр»:
>   ...
>   Здесь мрамор — свой. Край мрамором богат.
>   Театр будет круглый и высокий.

Вы мне предлагаете посчитать слоги чтобы обнаружить правильный ритм(скажу сразу, я этого никогда не делаю, ибо "слышу глазами" ритм - и все его нюансы, которые только можно передать на письме).

Здесь мрамор — свой. Край мрамором богат.
Театр будет круглый и высокий.

Первая строка - классический ямб, украшенный двумя симметричными спондеями.

Вторая
Т**еА**т**ы**р б**У**д**е**т кр**У**гл**ы**й **И** в**ы**с**О**к**и**й.
-/-/-/-/-/-
Если здесь полностопный ямб (без "антианакрузы"), то на "театр" приходится ***три*** слога.

То же и у Толстого. Так о каком "двусложии в односложных словах" повествует Квятковский? Либо он не умеет считать, либо он погрячился с формулировкой, либо его примеры неудачны. Я счел за благо видеть здесь третий фариант. Вас это обидело. Тогда я намекнул, что иначе получается еще обиднее. Все.

//------------

> Вам, behemothus - за бескомпромиссность и глубокие познания

Да не на чем. Вы зря это, кстати, насчет познаний. Людмила по части познаний мне сто очков даст. Вот когда дело до практики доходит, мы почему-то всегда расходимся кардинально.  Наверное, мне теория просто глаз еще не замылила. )))

Comment: Не, не хочется гласные вставлять. Идея с сонорными (или, как ниже изложено, по Квятковскому) мне больше по душе. 

А экспериментаторы... Каких только рифм не выдумывали. Не нравится мне ни "рубЫль", ни "декабЫрь", ни "театЫр". Но это уже вкусовщина. Имеют право быть...

Comment: ответил кратко в основном посте

Answer (score 2):

Я не знаю, где об этом можно почитать, но сонорный [м] тянется сколько угодно и приобретает   какой угодно мелодический рисунок, почти так же, как гласный, поэтому ничего удивительного в том, что возникает подобие слога.

Comment: Спасибо. Про слогообразующие сонорные мне уже подсказали приватно, а потом и сам по этому слову информацию нашел... в википедии  ;)

Answer (score 1):

[**Слог** | enc-dic.com](http://enc-dic.com/poet/Slog-415.html)

Поэтический словарь Квятковского говорит:
СЛОГ во 2 значении(фонетический) —
2) Гласный звук, согласный с гласным или группа звуков, произносимых единым выдыханием (экспирацией). Слоги могут быть из двух гласных (дифтонги), а иногда, наоборот, — без гласного звука (в метрических стихах), например:

***Ш-ш,*** слушайте! Собором положили... (А. Пушкин)
***Гм-гм,*** читатель благородный (А. Пушкин).

Или в стихотворной драме А. Майкова «Два мира»:

*Гет: Что, старец дремлет?

Дик: **Тс!** Молчи.

Как будто задремал немного.*

Характерно, что поэтический слух обнаруживает двусложие в таких односложных словах, как «центр» и «театр»:

*Жизнь — отражение лунного лика в воде,

Сфера, чей **центр** повсюду, окружность нигде.*
К. Бальмонт

*Здесь мрамор — свой. Край мрамором богат.

**Театр** будет круглый и высокий.*
В. Инбер

И наконец:

*Взял под руку его: «Ах, Антипатор

Васильевич! Что, как ваш кобелек?

Здоров ли он?.. Вы ездите в **театор**?».*
А. К. Толстой

Comment: А что, собственно, добавляет (кроме примеров) эта цитата?

Пример из Бальмонта, кстати, весьма сомнителен.
И так можно - трактовать и эдак. Строка все равно в конкретный размер не ложится. Учитывая, что Бальмонт вообще образец "кристального" чувтва метраЮ думаю, что там дополнительного слога нет. 

Все примеры с "театром" - тоже спорны.

Comment: >двусложие в таких ***односложных*** словах, как «центр» и ***«театр»***: 

Совсем запутался бедный аффтырь. Там очевидное ***трехсложное*** "тЕ-Ат(ы)р" с ударением на А, А не двусложное "тЯт(ы)р", как в живой речи.   
Но тут не буду настаивать, ибо это вроде как уже стихотворной традицией закреплено, просто формулировка "оставляет желать".

Comment: "бедный аффтырь" - знаток и теоретик стихосложения,сам поэт, автор поэтического словаря, признанного лучшим до сих пор. И формулировка нормальная. А прежде чем кого-то обвинять в некомпетентности("запутался"),Вы бы посчитали, математик ведь:
Жизнь/ — отра/жение/ лунного/ лика в во/де,1,4,7,10
Сфера, чей/ центор по/всюду, о/кружность ни/где.-  14710-дактиль, а с одним слогом не получается.

Comment: >"бедный аффтырь" - знаток и теоретик стихосложения,  
Ну хотя бы до трех-то он считать умеет?  

>Вы бы посчитали, математик ведь  

Людмила, разговоры про стихосложение я с Вами не веду вообще после предыдущего раза (история с "Троицей"). Мы в разных плоскостях понимания предмета.  
А разговоры с переходом на личность - тем более. Простите. 

Спросите лучше "титиретика", сколько и каких слогов он насчитал в слове "театр". Потом будем разбираться и с Бальмонтом. С аффтырем, разумеется, не Вами.

Comment: Спасибо за обширную информацию.

Comment: Уважаемый behemothus, мы действительно в разных плоскостях: вы о русском языке, а я о поэзии, о науке ритмологии, её мэтр как раз Квятковский. Почитайте для интереса, только без предвзятости: http://magazines.russ.ru/arion/2009/1/gu25.htm l Есть долгий слог(два гласных как один) ,краткий(полудольный, четвертьдольный). Спросили, где об этом почитать, я и написала(не Вам, а автору вопроса. И вдруг от Вас такое "уничижение" мэтра, как в "Ответах" было похожее по отношению к Розенталю, кот. там обозвали попом, полуграмотным евреем и ещё как-то, я просто оттуда ушла, без споров.

Comment: А насчёт слова"театр":в русском языке 2 слога, Вы правы.В ритмологии по Квятковскому именно в этой строфе -1,он читается кратко"т(иа)тр", не растягивается, иначе неверно будут переданы интонации автора, но Инбер протянула в другом месте:Здесь мра/мор — свой.// Край мра/мором/ богат.//
Теа/т(о)р бу/дет круг/лый и/ высо/кий.Это едва уловимо, но учит читать правильно. Мне было всегда сложно это понять: я читала так, как должно быть, как хотела слышать,а не как автор говорил, поэтому меня и не взяли в диалектологическую экспедицию, я бы никаких оттенков не услышала,но я это признаю, а Вы нет.

Comment: О переходе на личности - я бы тоже предпочитала видеть от Вас только Ваши ответы, без унизительных комментариев других участников, тем более унижения профессионалов- авторов источников.Если Вы их не знаете, это не значит, что их не знают все и их нет в науке.

Comment: Людмила, лучше бы личные разборки писали в личку. 
Мне кажется, что Вы находите в моих словах совсем не то, что надо.
Чуть позже отвечу предметно.

Comment: Уважаемые! Большое спасибо, что обратили внимание на порождающий данную проблему аспект (возникновение слогов без явного наличия гласных), а не узко ограничились темой обсуждения.  
Вам, Людмила, отдельное спасибо за объём предоставленной информации.  
Вам, behemothus - за бескомпромиссность и глубокие познания. Без пиетета прошлись по авторитетам или там по тонким фибрилляция моих орфоэпических вкусов? Главное, что с толком! "У носорога неважно со зрением, но это - не его проблемы". Ваш подход мои проблемы решать помогает. Заодно и потолще дискуссионную шкуру отращу... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы понять особенности произношение слов, в которых встречается сочетание согласных, надо знать следующее. Сонорные согласные - это особые звуки. По соотношению голоса и шума они занимают промежуточное положение между гласными и всеми остальными (шумными)согласными: при их произношение голос преобладает над шумом. Именно поэтому у сонорные согласные похожи на гласные звуки. Похожи тем, что могут образовывать слог, в случае, если они произносятся в абсолютном начале слова после шумных согласных или в абсолютном конце слова, но тогда уже после шумных согласных. В указанных позициях у сонорных согласных развивается гласный призвук - благодаря этому и образуется слог.

Comment: У меня в пояснении досадная неточность. Следует уточнить фонетическую позицию сонорных, способных к слогообразованию: В АБСОЛЮТНОМ НАЧАЛЕ СЛОВА ПЕРЕД ШУМНЫМИ. Во второй  части пояснения всё верно: В АБСОЛЮТНОМ КОНЦЕ СЛОВА ПОСЛЕ ШУМНОГО СОГЛАСНОГО

Comment: Так поправьте. 
Впрочем, имхо, большой нужды в том и нет. Все это можно посмотреть в учебниках.  
Вопрос, ***где и почему*** это происходит, здесь особо не стоит. Суть, как я понимаю, в отношении к самому явлению с точки зрения теории силабо-тонического стиха. Т.е. если поэт "слышит" этот "сонорный" слог (вне зависимости от причин), должен ли он этот слог использовать? И если да, то как это передать фонетически.  
Вот Шершеневич говорит о "непроизносимой гласной" в этом примере из Бальмонта, а автор вопроса гласную эту "вставлять не хочет". Вы на чьей стороне?